# RequiredFieldValidator .net 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Afternoon All,

I have two fileds that i require to be validated on a web form once the user clicks the submit button.  These web form also holds a Validation summary to make the user aware of the error message.

My code looks like this...

```
     <td>                       
         <asp:TextBox ID="txtOrganiser" runat="server"  ></asp:TextBox>      
     </td>
     <td>
         <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldVal0"
                     ControlToValidate="txtOrganiser" 
                     ErrorMessage="Meeting Organiser"
                     Text="*" 
                     runat="server" Display="None"/>
      </td>
      <td>      
         <asp:DropDownList ID="AgendaStatus" 
               runat="server" Height="24px" Width="125px"> </asp:DropDownList>        
      </td>    
      <td>
          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1"
                     ControlToValidate="AgendaStatus" 
                     ErrorMessage="Agenda Status"
                     Text="*" 
                     runat="server" Display="None"/>
      </td>
      <td>
          <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary"
            HeaderText="You must enter a value in the following fields:"
            DisplayMode="BulletList"
            EnableClientScript="true"
            runat="server"/>
      </td>
```

The code for the 'Meeting Organiser' works perfectly fine.  However the 'AgendaStatus' dropdown doesnt.  I think this is due to the fact that the dropdown list essentially already has a default value to prompt the user to select the item?

The Agenda dropdown uses this code...

```
 'Used for the Enum property on the web page for the dropdown (Agenda Template.aspx)
Private Sub BindStatus()
    AgendaStatus.DataSource = EnumHelper.ToList(GetType(AgendaStatus))

    AgendaStatus.DataTextField = "Value"
    AgendaStatus.DataValueField = "Key"
    AgendaStatus.DataBind()

    AgendaStatus.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem(" - Please Select -", "~"))
End Sub
```

And this piece of code...

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports SembCorp.CoreLib

Public Enum AgendaStatus
   <EnumDescription("Created")> _
   TempCreated = 1
   <EnumDescription("In Progress")> _
   InProgress = 2
   <EnumDescription("Completed")> _
   Completed = 3

End Enum
```

A error message displayed if the dropdown box doesnt have a selected item is...

```
Requested value '~' was not found.
```

I can see why this error is being displayed as the user has not selected one of the drop down option.  However i thought that i could add the RequiredFieldValidator tools to resolve this issue.  This has not worked and i do not have a solution.

Any help is much appriechiated in advance.

Regards
Betty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can set [`AppendDataboundItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.appenddatabounditems.aspx) to true, on this way you can add your default item declaratively on the aspx markup:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="AgendaStatus"
    AppendDataboundItems="true" 
    runat="server" Height="24px" Width="125px"> 
    <asp:ListItem Value="-1" Text=" - Please Select -"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Then you can set the validator's [`InitialValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.initialvalue.aspx) to `"-1"` to ensure that the first item is not a valid user option:

```
 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1"
                 InitialValue="-1"
                 ControlToValidate="AgendaStatus" 
                 ErrorMessage="Agenda Status"
                 Text="*" 
                 runat="server" Display="None"/>
```

Comment: Many Thanks for your solution so quickly.  This works a treat.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "~" from the list item value. Also set `AppendDataBoundItems="true"` for the `DropDownList`